# Rest API downloading Idea AttachmentBody

Tags: rest-api, ideas, base64

When downloading Idea's AttachmentBody field per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm), the download gets a 400.

Example:

```
services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Idea/087c00000009GDVAA2/AttachmentBody
services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Attachment/00Pc0000005Ph5KEAS/Body
```

Download for Attachment succeeds. Can the Idea's attachment be downloaded through the API?

Comment: Tried with a newer API version than 37?

Comment: Are you trying it via workbench or any rest client?

Comment: Still the same issue on curl.
Contacted Salesforce. Apparently, it is a bug and they're working on it.